# pass mouseevent to component onclick

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to capture mouse coordinates in a Angular component.

Here is the html in question:

```
<div id="container" class="fullSize" style="height:100%;" (click)="onClick(ev)"></div>
```

Here is the component function in the corresponding typescript file:

```
onClick( ev : MouseEvent ) {
  console.log("x:" + ev.clientX);
}
```

And the error in the console:

```
Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined'
```

What would be the correct way of passing that MouseEvent to my component function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `$event` to pass `MouseEvent` object to your click handler.

So simply write:

```
(click)="onClick($event)"
```

See also

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-and-event-handling-statements

Comment: you're my hero!
Is there a reason why this specific identifier is required?

Answer (score 1):

Current best practice:

```html
<div id="container" class="fullSize" style="height:100%;" (click)=onClick($event.clientX)"></div>
```

```js
onClick(myClientX: number) { 
  console.log("x: " + myClientX);
}
```

Per current guideline found here: [Passing $event is a dubious practice](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice)

Comment: what about custom generic button component?
In that case I need to cover all the user cases?